# update value in comma separated and replace with value in query

Tags: mysql

iam having table like this

```
id    name       sol_id

1      abc       2,5,8
2       dt       5,9,10
```

here i want to add  some value(10) to id=1 of sol_id,so value 10 will be added with id=1 and at the same time value 10 of id=2 replace with some empty value i want output like this

```
  id    name       sol_id

  1      abc       2,5,8,10(here updating)
  2       dt       5,9 (10 removing)
```

i wrote query like this but its performs one operation not both

```
UPDATE my_table SET sol_id=REPLACE(sol_id,',10,',',')
and sol_id = Concat(sol_id, ',', 10) where id = 1
```

is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but clunky.

Basically you would do

```
UPDATE table SET SET field = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN <formula for the case of id=1>
    WHEN 2 THEN <formula for the case of id=2>
END
WHERE ID IN (1, 2);
```

There's no great advantage over running several queries inside a TRANSACTION and, if necessary, a suitable lock on the table.

Comment: here "formula" means @lserni